# Docker compose cannot bind to any port

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been trying to run `docker-compose up` command but everytime it errors out saying the ports are not available. I have tried all the random ports I can think of but they all give me the same error
Here's my full error:

```
ERROR: for 5123b7524073_interaction  Cannot start service interaction: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4005: bind: 
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

ERROR: for content  Cannot start service content: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4000: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

ERROR: for mongo  Cannot start service mongo: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:40000: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

ERROR: for user  Cannot start service user: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4003: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

ERROR: for interaction  Cannot start service interaction: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:4005: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

and here's my compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    content:
        container_name: content
        restart: always
        build: ./Content
        ports:
            - "4000:3000"
        external_links:
            - mongo

    interaction:
        container_name: interaction
        restart: always
        build: ./Interaction
        ports:
            - "4005:3002"
        external_links:
            - mongo

    user:
        container_name: user
        restart: always
        build: ./User
        ports:
            - "4003:3001"
        external_links:
            - mongo

    mongo:
        container_name: mongo
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - "40000:27017"
```

I have tried to use `net stop winnat` before running docker and made sure there were no blocked ports I was accessing by running `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`.

Here's my output for running netsh

```
Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
      5357        5357
      7080        7080
     50000       50059     *

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem here? I am running docker on win 10

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem, my antivirus was blocking docker from accessing those ports. I just made sure to run docker desktop with admin privileges after reinstalling it. it asked me firewall permissions from `com.docker.backend` or smth like that, make sure to give the permissions and it worked now